# Time to timeout session

Tags: java, session, servlets, timeout, wicket

Is there a way to find out how long the session of the user remains valid ( until it times-out)?

I would like to show this time on a page.

I know how to set the timeout, but could not find how to get the current time to time-out.

Comment: As you accept below answer, could you please update how you apply it to your page's code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should track the time with plain JavaScript in the browser and reset with every Ajax/WebSocket call.

You cannot track it at the server because to check the time you need to make a request and this will renew the session.

Comment: Could you please explain detail about how to detect `Ajax/WebSocket call` by Javascript so that I could reset the time countdown?

Comment: @Pham Basically, you render a piece of javascript that sets a  variable `sessionTimeout`. Subscribe to the wicket-ajax-events, if they are succesfull, reset the `sessionTimeout`

Answer (score 1):

There is a [getLastAccessedTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#%20getLastAccessedTime%20on%20the%20Session%20object,%20that%20might%20help.) on the session object, that might help.

Comment: Am I correct to assume the the timeout will occur at ( current-time - getLastAccessedTime()) > getMaxInactiveInterval() ?

Comment: But to use this method you need to make an http request, i.e. it will renew the session.