# Display time to timeout session

Tags: c#, asp.net

As Title, how to check/ display time to timeout session in the menu page?

We have web applicaion using `ASP.NET, C#` with `menu.aspx` is main page, when we click to menu then a new page will be opened. User could idle or interact with child page to reset session timeout.

I searched and found [this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263039/time-to-timeout-session) answer said to use javascript and reset timer whenerver detect an Ajax/WebSocket call.

But how to detect an Ajax/WebSocket call to reset the countdown?

Thank for any help!

Comment: Do you have a MasterPage?

Comment: @DragandDrop Yes, I have one.

Comment: In page load of my master page I relunch my js timer.. Everytime the master is displayed the timer is a new one.

Comment: @DragandDrop A sorry, forgot to mention we use ajax and call webservices to web server for doing business logic, not use postback in most pages.

Comment: `addEventListener` on the XmlHttpReq, But I have no exemple of that in my code bag